# How do Refresh List View when adding new elements

Tags: android, listview

What i am doing is showing a list view and reload its data when list is Moved to last Element.
Its working fine but the problem is when it reloads it went back to the top element in list. I want List to be stayed at same position and append new Elements below it.

Here is what i am doing

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount
            && totalItemCount != 0) {
        if (flag_loading == false) {
            flag_loading = true;
            toast("Last view");
            loadMorePost();
        }
    }

}

private void loadMorePost() {
    page_no = page_no + 1;
    String url = "api/post/index/page_no/" + page_no;
    syncManager.sendToServer(url, null, this);
}



        if (action.equals("index") && controller.equals("post")) {
            if (status) {
                //postItemsList.clear();
                JSONArray postArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post_list");
                if (postArray.length() <= 0) {
                    toast("No Post Available");
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < postArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = postArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ItemsAllPost data = new ItemsAllPost();
                        data.user_first_name = obj
                                .getString("User_first_name");
                        data.user_address = obj.getString("User_address");
                        data.user_post_count = obj
                                .getString("user_post_count");
                        data.description = obj
                                .getString("post_description");
                        data.category_id = obj.getString("category_id");
                        data.create_user_id = obj
                                .getString("create_user_id");
                        data.post_image = obj.getString("post_image");
                        data.user_ph_no = obj.getString("User_ph_no");
                        data.user_long = obj.getString("User_long");
                        data.date = obj.getString("date");
                        data.post_fav = obj.getString("post_fav");
                        data.amount = obj.getString("amount");
                        data.id = obj.getString("id");
                        data.category_title = obj
                                .getString("category_title");
                        data.time_period = obj.getString("time_period");
                        data.is_private = obj.getString("is_private");
                        data.fav_count = obj.getString("fav_count");
                        JSONArray imagesarry = obj
                                .getJSONArray("post_image");
                        data.imgList = new String[imagesarry.length()];
                        for (int j = 0; j < imagesarry.length(); j++) {
                            data.imgList[j] = imagesarry.getString(j);
                        }
                        data.view_count = obj.getString("view_count");
                        data.user_email = obj.getString("User_email");
                        data.user_lat = obj.getString("User_lat");
                        data.title = obj.getString("post_title");
                        postItemsList.add(data);
                    }
                    inflateList(postItemsList);
                }
            }
        }


private void inflateList(ArrayList<ItemsAllPost> postItemsList) {
    if (postItemsList.size() > 0) {
        adapter = new AllPostAdapter((BaseActivity) activity,
                postItemsList, userDataFrag);
        allpostsLV.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Any Help
What should i do

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Make sure that you adding new elements to the same list that is set to source of your adapter, after adding call adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged

Comment: I have done this in inflateList()

Comment: Updated my question where i am notifying my list view

Comment: setAdapter already doing notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: do you want to list stay at the end and when new post comming continues from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using one List to store your data :

```
private List<ItemsAllPost> datas;
```

init your adapter only one when the first time you get data :

```
adapter = new AllPostAdapter((BaseActivity) activity,
            postItemsList, datas);
```

when you load more data finish just add all extra data to : datas

```
 datas.addAll(moredataList);
```

and only need to call :

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I cant see where **postItemsList** is declared so I guess you made it like  the : datas variable so you can only call : adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  but **don't** re-init your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

try this

add this code where you get your updated data and also adapter : adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: i have updated my question added the code where i am notifying my list view

Comment: have you try to print updated data ?  just for debugging purpose where you get your updated data . Just to make sure data should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

remove these lines :

```
     private void inflateList(ArrayList<ItemsAllPost> postItemsList) {
    if (postItemsList.size() > 0) {
        adapter = new AllPostAdapter((BaseActivity) activity,
                postItemsList, userDataFrag);
        allpostsLV.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

and add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after

```
 postItemsList.add(data);
```